# Redirecting old website with multiple pages to a one page website

Tags: seo, redirects

I've created a website for a client, they said they didnt't care that SEO would be affected so I decided to create a completely new website with a different structure than their old website.

They said that they had no traffic to their website anyways, but they are ranking first for their company name(a pretty unique name).

Their old website had 3 pages that I basicly merged into a one page website and uploaded with a different domain name. This website isn't ranking very well yet however it was just uploaded 2 days ago.

Can I redirect the entire old website to the new one and keep their SEO ranking or will it be penalized after doing so?

Comment: You mention 'redirecting' so I assume when you say 'new website' you mean a new domain and content. You might be much better off just keeping the old domain and replacing the content with what you created.  That way you have much less risk of Google having to figure everything out and losing rank.

Comment: Yes I mean a new domain with new content. They wanted another domain name and I explained that SEO would be affected if I created a completely new website with a new domain and new content. However I want to do everything possible to keep the traffic they had to their old website and transfer it to the new website.

Answer (score 1):

You can do 301 redirects which will transfer much of the google juice from the old to the new site, however you will likely not have the domain authority on the new domain which will reduce the rankings a bit - although this will come back over time.

Why not put new content on the old domain?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My client wanted another domain name and I explained that SEO would be affected if I created a new website with a new domain and new content. They still persitsted and wanted a new domain. However I still want to do everything possible to keep the traffic they had to their old website and transfer it to the new website.

Comment: 301 redirects are what you are after then.